# How can I fetch/download something from a link inside an api?

Tags: c#, api, etl

So, this might be a dumb question but I got this website (http://dados.cvm.gov.br/dados/FI/DOC/INF_DIARIO/DADOS/) that I need to create an ETL to extract this data. As of this moment I got this API (http://dados.cvm.gov.br/api/3/action/package_show?id=fi-doc-inf_diario) that seems to be the right one with the files, but they are inside the objects within the API, and my ETLBOX doesn't seem to get them.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Can you advise what issue you face with downloading them?

Comment: I need my ETL to extract those files in the first link, the API I have (2nd link) doesn't seem to contain the information inside the files, only have the URL inside to download it (like when you download in the first one). It's a bit confusing I know, but when i tried to run it, I got a blank table in my SQL

Comment: To what database are you going to save that?

Comment: A local SQL server.